# How to make an API request with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I'm making an API request to USDA database but I can't get the right info with React. It just throw me different CORS errors that I can't solve.

I tried the same API request with Javascript all alone and it worked perfectly but now in React I can't get it right.

This is on Javascript

```
const BASE_API = `https://api.nal.usda.gov/fdc/v1/search?api_key=api_key`;
async function getData(url) {
  const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
          generalSearchInput: "Cheddar cheese"
      }),
      headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
  });
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
}
```

And this is in React

```
fetchFoodID = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("https://api.nal.usda.gov/fdc/v1/search?api_key=api_key",{
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
            generalSearchInput: "Cheddar"
        }),
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({
        data: data
    });
};
```

With Javascript I can get the food list with the search terms but in React it just throw different cors problems.

Comment: The third line doesn't look right

Comment: `It just throw me different CORS errors` ... what are these CORS errors *specifically* - because there are different errors for different reasons

Comment: See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question. - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fastest way to resolve this type of CORS problem is to add an entry in your hosts file mapping localhost to some address and develop from there. Obviously, this is a quick and dirty solution (since it only fixes the problem on your local machine) but if you're developing a small project for your own learning then it's a not a bad way to do it.

```
127.0.0.1 your_custom_address
```

I did run your code and it worked fine.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try that for now <3